# How much money would Jack and his crew earn with the rest of methylamine?

Tags: breaking-bad

Walt earned 74 million dollars with the methylamine.

In *[Felina](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2301455/)*, Walt theorizes that Jack's crew is running out of methylamine.

So by this time, how much money would Jack have earned with the cooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Walt estimated that the methylamine, once cooked, would be worth $300 million.

His deal with Declan was a 65/35 split.

At the time of his "retirement" he had about 80 million in the storage unit. 80 million is 65% of 123 million.

There were some other expenses. I assume the payments to the pest control company came out of Walt's 65%. Walt gave $5 million to Jesse.

Overall let's say Walt had cooked about half the methylamine. Jack's gang could thus cook the other half and make as much as $150 million.